# how can I correctly upzip .jar and recombine it after making some change to MANIFEST.MF

Tags: maven, jar

I unzip a jar file using 7zip , here is the origin content of 
/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: liuyang
Class-Path: . lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar lib/sqljdbc4-4.0.jar
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_171
Main-Class: org.tinyradius.test.TestServer
```

what I want to do is add one addtional Class-Path , the final content after I change is :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: liuyang
Class-Path: . lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar lib/sqljdbc4-4.0.jar
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_171
Main-Class: org.tinyradius.test.TestServer
```

you can see I only add  lib/sqljdbc4-4.0.jar

now I goto window command line and type :

```
jar cfv tinyradius-0.9.9.jar META-INF org
```

and my folder looks like this :

[image]

after this command finish ,  it do appear a new jar file named: tinyradius-0.9.9.jar 
but after I unzip this new jar file , I find new MANIFEST.MF have such content :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.8.0_171 (Oracle Corporation)
```

why it is so different with what I updated ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary folder on your desktop. Drop the jar into that folder. Rename the jar `tinyradius-0.9.9.jar` to `tinyradius-0.9.9.zip` and unzip it. Make the change to the manifest. Select all the files and compress them. Rename the zip back to jar.

Comment: hi , after I  doing as you told and upload this jar file to centos , and type: java -jar tinyradius-0.9.9.jar   .    It raise an error : Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile tinyradius-0.9.9.jar